# Inconsistent parent directory of all symlinks

Tags: nautilus, bash, filesystem, symbolic-link

A large portion of my system depends on symbolic links, so this is a very serious problem. I do something like the following

```
cd
mkdir test
mkdir other
cd test
ln -s ../other/
# So ~/test contains a symlink to ~/other
cd other
dirname `pwd`
# So far so good; prints /home/user/test
ls ..
# Prints the contents of /home/user (???)
cd ..
# Now we're back in /home/user/test
```

So the parent of the current working directory and `..` refer to two different locations in the context of `ls` (and also `cp`), but not `cd`.

I have observed this problem for all symlinks on my system, both existing and new (like the example above), and on multiple filesystems. The same thing happens in nautilus, which now shows the breadcrumbs of the physical path of any symlink I click, instead of the relative path. To my knowledge, I did not change anything that would cause an error like this, and booting an old kernel did not appear to fix the problem. I have seen many posts desiring this behavior, but none correcting it.

Any thoughts on this issue would be greatly appreciated. I am running Ubuntu Linux 12.10 3.11.0-18-generic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your shell remembers when you `cd` into a directory via a symlink and uses that information when you `cd ..`. If you use `bash` or `zsh` you can execute the command `set -P` in order  to make `cd` behave the same as `cp` (i.e., make it ignore symbolic links so that  in your example `cd ..` would take you to `/home/user`, not `/home/user/test`).

Refer to [this Unix & Linux SE question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83966/cp-somefile-copies-to-a-different-directory-after-cding-via-a-symbolic-link) for more information including a hack to make `cp` behave like `cd` instead of the opposite.